# Parsing xml with using XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

I am facing an issue with below xml content while using xpath.it is noticed that CDATA tag is causing the issue. if i remove the line `<![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` from XML then the issue is getting resolved.

The XPATH i am using is **/Configuration/ConfigurationBlock/configSNMP/snmpSet**

```
    <Configuration>
        <ConfigurationBlock protocol="snmp">
        <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configSNMP>
        <snmpSet groupName="NO_DEVICE">
            <snmpVarbindSet groupName="table" isScalar="false" mibName="MIB" mibOverride="" setOperation="CREATE" tableName="table">
                <snmpVarbind OID="1.3.6.1.2.1989" bitsType="false" isModifiable="false" isRowStatus="true" stringType="" textualConventionType="RowStatus" type="INTEGER" value="4"/>
            </snmpVarbindSet>
        </snmpSet>
    </configSNMP>
</ConfigurationBlock>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: That's not valid XML. The square brackets in your `CDATA` aren't balanced.

Comment: CDATA means "character data". It means "the things in here are not elements, even if they look like elements". It's an explicit instruction to the parser to say "don't treat this stuff as structured XML". If you want it treated as structured XML, don't put it in CDATA.

Answer (score 0):

Your CDATA block is never closed. If everything in the ConfigurationBlock was supposed to be CDATA, then your XML would need to look like this:

```
<Configuration>
  <ConfigurationBlock protocol="snmp">
    <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configSNMP>
        <snmpSet groupName="NO_DEVICE">
            <snmpVarbindSet groupName="table" isScalar="false" mibName="MIB" mibOverride="" setOperation="CREATE" tableName="table">
                <snmpVarbind OID="1.3.6.1.2.1989" bitsType="false" isModifiable="false" isRowStatus="true" stringType="" textualConventionType="RowStatus" type="INTEGER" value="4"/>
            </snmpVarbindSet>
        </snmpSet>
    </configSNMP>
    ]]>
  </ConfigurationBlock>
</Configuration>
```

All of the content will be evaluated as an escaped XML string, the equivalent of it being:

```
<Configuration>
    <ConfigurationBlock protocol="snmp">
        &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;
    &lt;configSNMP&gt;
        &lt;snmpSet groupName="NO_DEVICE"&gt;
            &lt;snmpVarbindSet groupName="table" isScalar="false" mibName="MIB" mibOverride="" setOperation="CREATE" tableName="table"&gt;
                &lt;snmpVarbind OID="1.3.6.1.2.1989" bitsType="false" isModifiable="false" isRowStatus="true" stringType="" textualConventionType="RowStatus" type="INTEGER" value="4"/&gt;
            &lt;/snmpVarbindSet&gt;
        &lt;/snmpSet&gt;
    &lt;/configSNMP&gt;

</ConfigurationBlock>
</Configuration>
```

If you want to be able to evaluate an XPath that addresses the configSNMP elements, then it has to be XML nodes (remove the CDATA block), or parse that escaped XML string to evaluate as an XML fragment, using [`parse-xml()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-parse-xml):

```
/Configuration/ConfigurationBlock/parse-xml(substring-after(., '?>'))/configSNMP/snmpSet
```